# My first Unit to Run Ubuntu

Tags: upgrade, dell

I got hold of this computer and I am wondering if anyone would enlighten me as to whether it will be able to run ubuntu . I am new to the linux world and need advice.

I have a Dell Precision M4500 Core i7
M640  15.6"  2.8GHz  8GB RAM
500GB  HDD  1920 x 1080

I think The Unit is probably older than Alabama if it can run a proper version of Linux Ubuntu I down with it.

Thankyou good neighbors
Cad Willager

Cad

Comment: Thankyou for your timely response

Comment: 64-bit CPU, 8GB of RAM - You should be able to run pretty much any of the Ubuntu flavors, although default GNOME might be a bit heavy considering this hardware is from around 2011 from what I see.  I'd suggest going with Xubuntu or Mate, of if you have experience with Linux and don't mind minimalism - install server edition and put Openbox or Blackbox desktop on it.

Answer (score 0):

The first generation of core i7 processors should run fine. Just grab a bootable Ubuntu USB stick and boot the computer using the USB stick. If you are still unsure get the LTS 16.04 version and boot it. It is still supported until 2021.